# Присваиваю string json в dynamic object, а после присваиваю данные dynamic object в DTO и выдаётся ошибка в Prodoction inux server, но работает в WIN

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Во время разработки в режиме Debug работает все отлично а после публикации на server linux выдает ошибку на присвоение данных, что я делаю я получаю string json и присваиваю его в dynamic object а после редактирую нужные поля и приравниваю каждую деталь в мой DTO, именно при присвоение у меня выдаётся ошибка что можно сделать я не понимаю. Вот код реализации

```
PersonDTO person = new();
if (jsonHeader.company != null)
        {
            person.Name = jsonHeader.company.name;
            person.NameEN = jsonHeader.company.name;
            person.ShortName = jsonHeader.company.shortName;
            person.ShortNameEn = jsonHeader.company.shortName;
            person.InnOrPinfl = jsonHeader.company.tin;

            var kfs = await Context.Kfs.Where(x => x.Code == jsonHeader.company.kfs).Select(x => new Kfs { Id = x.Id }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (kfs != null)
                person.KfsId = kfs.Id;

            var getoked = await Context.Okeds.Where(x => x.Code == jsonHeader.company.oked).Select(x => new Oked { Id = x.Id }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (getoked != null)
            {
                var oked = new PersonOkedDTO()
                {
                    OkedId = getoked.Id,
                    PersonStatusId = 1
                };
                okeds.Add(oked);
            }

            var opf = await Context.Opfs.Where(x => x.Code == jsonHeader.company.opf).Select(x => new Opf { Id = x.Id }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (opf != null)
                person.OpfId = opf.Id;

            var soogu = await Context.Soogus.Where(x => x.Code == jsonHeader.company.soogu).Select(x => new Soogu { Id = x.Id }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (soogu != null)
                person.SooguId = soogu.Id;

            person.PersonTypeId = 2;
            person.RiskLevelId = 2;
            person.PersonStatusId = 1;
            person.ResidentDefinitionId = 1;
            person.TaxExemptId = 1;

            person.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(jsonHeader.company.registrationDate);

            var currency = await Context.Currencies.Where(x => x.Code == jsonHeader.company.businessFundCurrency).Select(x => new Currency { Id = x.Id }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (currency != null && jsonHeader.company.businessFund != "0")
            {
                CapitalDTO capitalDTO = new CapitalDTO()
                {
                    CurrencyId = currency.Id,
                    Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(jsonHeader.company.businessFund),
                    PersonStatusId = 1
                };
                capitals.Add(capitalDTO);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Текст ошибки какой? Секретный? Где здесь dynamic?

Comment: @aepot нет 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: А в логах что? Текст исключения какой?